# Actions of CRUD are wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, action, crud

I'm newbie in Ruby on Rails. Recently I created a project and add some gems to support my app. But several problems started occurring. I created two new routes to use Devise with the same model. Then, the application does not use the correct routes to the actions. To use the EDIT action, the application is redirecting to the CREATE action. What is causing this problem? Follow my files:

My routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do  

  as :member do
    resource :registration, only: [:create], :path => '/members'
  end
  resources :members_admin, :controller => 'members'

  devise_for :members, :controllers => { :registrations => 'registrations'}

  resources :managments
  resources :expenses
  resources :incomings
  resources :members
  resources :registrations
  get 'home/index'
  root to:'home#index'


#  patch 'members_admin' => "members#update",  :as => "members/update"

end
```

end

form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @member,url: members_admin_index_path, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal member", :method => :post } do |f| %>

  <% if @member.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_expl" class="panel panel-danger">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"><%= pluralize(@member.errors.count, "erro") %> impediu(ram) que fosse criado:</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
        <% @member.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name, :class => 'control-label col-lg-2' %>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <%= f.text_field :name,autofocus: true, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <%=f.error_span(:name) %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :email, :class => 'control-label col-lg-2' %>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <%= f.email_field :email, :class => 'form-control' %>
      </div>
      <%=f.error_span(:email) %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password, :class => 'control-label col-lg-2' %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
      <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", :class => 'form-control'%>
    </div>
    <%=f.error_span(:password) %>
  </div>

 <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, :class => 'control-label col-lg-2' %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
      <em>(Insira no mínimo <%= @minimum_password_length %> caracteres.)</em>
    <% end %>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", :class => 'form-control'%>
    </div>
    <%=f.error_span(:password_confirmation) %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-3">
      <%= f.label :situation %>
      <%= f.check_box :situation, :class => 'col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-2' %>
    </div>
    <%=f.error_span(:situation) %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :function, :class => 'control-label col-lg-2' %>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <%= f.text_field :function, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <%=f.error_span(:function) %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :start_Managment, :class => 'control-label col-lg-2' %>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <%= f.date_select :start_Managment, start_year: 2001, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <%=f.error_span(:start_Managment) %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :dt_Admission, :class => 'control-label col-lg-2' %>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <%= f.date_select :dt_Admission, start_year: 2001, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <%=f.error_span(:dt_Admission) %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
      <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                members_path, :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
    </div>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

members_controller

```
class MembersController < InheritedResources::Base
  before_action :set_member, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_member!

  # GET /members
  # GET /members.json

  def pundit_user
    current_member
  end

  def pundit_user
    current_member
  end

  def index
    @members = Member.all
  end

  # GET /members/1
  # GET /members/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /members/new
  def new
    @members = Member.all
    authorize @members
    new!
  end

  # GET /members/1/edit
  def edit
    @members = Member.all
    authorize @members
  end

  # POST /members
  # POST /members.json
  def create
    @members = Member.all
    authorize Member
    create! { members_url }
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /members/1
  # PATCH/PUT /members/1.json
  def update
    update! {members_url }
  end

  # DELETE /members/1
  # DELETE /members/1.json
  def destroy
    @members = Member.all
    authorize @members
    destroy! { members_url }
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_member
      @member = Member.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_permit
      @members = Member.all
    end

    private
    def permitted_params
      params.permit(:member => [:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation,:dt_Admission, :situation, :function, :start_Managment])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def member_params
      params.require(:member).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :dt_Admission, :situation, :function, :start_Managment)
    end
end
```

Result of 'rake routes'

```
Routes

Routes match in priority from top to bottom
Helper  HTTP Verb   Path    Controller#Action
Path / Url          
registration_path   POST    /members(.:format)  registrations#create
members_admin_index_path    GET     /members_admin(.:format)    members#index
    POST    /members_admin(.:format)    members#create
new_members_admin_path  GET     /members_admin/new(.:format)    members#new
edit_members_admin_path     GET     /members_admin/:id/edit(.:format)   members#edit
members_admin_path  GET     /members_admin/:id(.:format)    members#show
    PATCH   /members_admin/:id(.:format)    members#update
    PUT     /members_admin/:id(.:format)    members#update
    DELETE  /members_admin/:id(.:format)    members#destroy
new_member_session_path     GET     /members/sign_in(.:format)  devise/sessions#new
member_session_path     POST    /members/sign_in(.:format)  devise/sessions#create
destroy_member_session_path     DELETE  /members/sign_out(.:format)     devise/sessions#destroy
member_password_path    POST    /members/password(.:format)     devise/passwords#create
new_member_password_path    GET     /members/password/new(.:format)     devise/passwords#new
edit_member_password_path   GET     /members/password/edit(.:format)    devise/passwords#edit
    PATCH   /members/password(.:format)     devise/passwords#update
    PUT     /members/password(.:format)     devise/passwords#update
cancel_member_registration_path     GET     /members/cancel(.:format)   registrations#cancel
member_registration_path    POST    /members(.:format)  registrations#create
new_member_registration_path    GET     /members/sign_up(.:format)  registrations#new
edit_member_registration_path   GET     /members/edit(.:format)     registrations#edit
    PATCH   /members(.:format)  registrations#update
    PUT     /members(.:format)  registrations#update
    DELETE  /members(.:format)  registrations#destroy
    GET     /members_admin/:nome(.:format)  members#edit
member_admin_index_path     GET     /member_admin(.:format)     member_admin#index
    POST    /member_admin(.:format)     member_admin#create
new_member_admin_path   GET     /member_admin/new(.:format)     member_admin#new
edit_member_admin_path  GET     /member_admin/:id/edit(.:format)    member_admin#edit
member_admin_path   GET     /member_admin/:id(.:format)     member_admin#show
    PATCH   /member_admin/:id(.:format)     member_admin#update
    PUT     /member_admin/:id(.:format)     member_admin#update
    DELETE  /member_admin/:id(.:format)     member_admin#destroy
managments_path     GET     /managments(.:format)   managments#index
    POST    /managments(.:format)   managments#create
new_managment_path  GET     /managments/new(.:format)   managments#new
edit_managment_path     GET     /managments/:id/edit(.:format)  managments#edit
managment_path  GET     /managments/:id(.:format)   managments#show
    PATCH   /managments/:id(.:format)   managments#update
    PUT     /managments/:id(.:format)   managments#update
    DELETE  /managments/:id(.:format)   managments#destroy
expenses_path   GET     /expenses(.:format)     expenses#index
    POST    /expenses(.:format)     expenses#create
new_expense_path    GET     /expenses/new(.:format)     expenses#new
edit_expense_path   GET     /expenses/:id/edit(.:format)    expenses#edit
expense_path    GET     /expenses/:id(.:format)     expenses#show
    PATCH   /expenses/:id(.:format)     expenses#update
    PUT     /expenses/:id(.:format)     expenses#update
    DELETE  /expenses/:id(.:format)     expenses#destroy
incomings_path  GET     /incomings(.:format)    incomings#index
    POST    /incomings(.:format)    incomings#create
new_incoming_path   GET     /incomings/new(.:format)    incomings#new
edit_incoming_path  GET     /incomings/:id/edit(.:format)   incomings#edit
incoming_path   GET     /incomings/:id(.:format)    incomings#show
    PATCH   /incomings/:id(.:format)    incomings#update
    PUT     /incomings/:id(.:format)    incomings#update
    DELETE  /incomings/:id(.:format)    incomings#destroy
members_path    GET     /members(.:format)  members#index
    POST    /members(.:format)  members#create
new_member_path     GET     /members/new(.:format)  members#new
edit_member_path    GET     /members/:id/edit(.:format)     members#edit
member_path     GET     /members/:id(.:format)  members#show
    PATCH   /members/:id(.:format)  members#update
    PUT     /members/:id(.:format)  members#update
    DELETE  /members/:id(.:format)  members#destroy
registrations_path  GET     /registrations(.:format)    registrations#index
    POST    /registrations(.:format)    registrations#create
new_registration_path   GET     /registrations/new(.:format)    registrations#new
edit_registration_path  GET     /registrations/:id/edit(.:format)   registrations#edit
    GET     /registrations/:id(.:format)    registrations#show
    PATCH   /registrations/:id(.:format)    registrations#update
    PUT     /registrations/:id(.:format)    registrations#update
    DELETE  /registrations/:id(.:format)    registrations#destroy
home_index_path     GET     /home/index(.:format)   home#index
root_path   GET     /   home#index
```

Please, I need help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the competing routes and it looks like you almost have it working. I have had this issue before where you can't create a user, or for your case a member once you are logged in.

In the routes file try doing something like this, just change user to member and make sure you are telling the registration controller to have the create member default to devise's create.

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'registration'}, :path_names => { :'sign_up.html.erb' => 'register'}   
resources :users, :only => [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :new, :create ]  
resources :users_admin, :controller => 'users'
```

**registration_controller.rb**

```
class RegistrationController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    super
  end
end
```

Also next time please post a stacktrace to help with reading what is going on.

Comment: Okay! Thank you very much. I need to create the new file for sign up? The Sign Up to login is ok. The issue is the CRUD of the model...

Comment: What part of the crud model are you having issues with after the route update?

Comment: If I update the routes following your instructions I have other problem. I can't do login. The app returns: "Couldn't find Member with 'id'=sign_in".

Comment: But If comment the line "resources :members, :only => [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :new, :create ] ", work it.

Comment: I try using routes "members_admin" for the CRUD. In same path (members), the user is created but I dont need to log in him.

Answer (score 0):

Man do you have to use the method **PUT** or **PATCH** to EDIT. The routes are the same, but the HTTP method is different. I think do you have to organize your routes because are a bit confused.

This way you broken the Rails pattern, so you will have problem. Your form doesn't work to **EDIT** and **CREATE** because you declared that will respond by the POST method, and your URL is sending to **members_admin_index_path**.

My opinion is that you should try to refactor this, otherwise you will have some problems later.